# Best Online Video Tutorial Source to Learn Web Development similar to Lynda.com

Tags: ajax

Please suggest premium or free online video sources that address web development.

I'm looking for the satisfy the following areas in particular.

1. Web architecture and planning
2. Web Usability and Design
3. Specific programming languages/frameworks namely (PHP, RoR, javascript, CSS)
4. Database Design
5. AJAX, jQuery
6. Any other areas needed to be a top notch developer (Note I didn't mean 'web designer', or 'web programmer')

So far the only great premium sites I'm aware of are lynda.com (for everything) and Peepcode.com (RoR). I know there's more out there like them. Please share.

Comment: lynda.com to learn php and javascript? Are you kidding me? Their JavaScript training covers outdated concepts and their training isn't really training - it consists of someone showing you how they did something in JavaScript. Worst yet, they show you the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best foundational programming information that I've found is Stanford Open Campus, specifically:

[CS106A](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111)

Here are some other resources to compete with Lynda.com

[UDEMY](http://www.udemy.com)

[Learnable](http://learnable.com)

[Video2Brain](http://www.video2brain.com)

[Creative Live](http://www.creativelive.com)

[Kelby](http://kelbytraining.com)

[VTC](http://vtc.com)

[TUTSPLUS](http://tutsplus.com)

[Digital Tutors](http://www.digitaltutors.com)

[Team Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com)

[Code Academy](http://www.codeacademy.com)

[Code School](http://www.codeschool.com)

[Peepcode](http://www.peepcode.com)

[TotalTraining](http://www.totaltraining.com)

Answer (score 3):

I just found a good resource:

Harvard CS-75 - Building Dynamic Websites

http://academicearth.org/courses/building-dynamic-websites

A previous version is also on iTunes.

Comment: The course can also be found on CS75.tv, along with transcript, video of sessions, sample code, assignment, etc.  Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

How about lynda.com's main competitor (but number two, I think), http://www.vtc.com.